# .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 dont open the page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make a error page for my website. At the moment I make it 100% local. I have this 3 lines in my `.htaccess` file

```
ErrorDocument 404 error_page.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^404 error_page.html
```

And thats my `error_page.html`

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 error
</body>
</html>
```

If I write a url that dosen't exists I get the filename as ouput.
And if I use the rewrite url I get the correct ouput (file, not only the name). What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ErrorDocument 404` needs full URI relative from your site root or absolute URL starting at `http://...`. Try

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_page.html
```